# How to display all bandwidth values in iperf

Tags: grep, iperf

I want to capture all bandwidth value in iperf not only Mbits size but also bits and Kbits as well.

```
[3] 0.0 - 1.0 sec 128 Kbytes 1.05 Mbits/sec
[3] 1.0 - 2.0 sec 0 Kbytes 0.00 bits/sec
[3] 2.0 - 3.0 sec 90 Kbytes 900.5 Kbits/sec
```

So far I know about this

```
iperf -c 10.0.0.1 -i 1 -t 100 | grep -Po '[0-9.]*(?= Mbits/sec)'
```

but that only captures Mbits value. How to capture bits/sec and Kbits/sec as well at the same time with Mbits/sec?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but in case someone stumbles upon it, you could add an optional character class to your grep:

```
grep -Po '[0-9.]*(?= [KM]*bits/sec)'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```c
iperf -c 10.0.0.1 -i 1 -t 100 | awk '{print$5}' FPAT=[.0-9]+
```

- `FPAT=[.0-9]+` defines a field as one or more of `.0-9`
- `{print$5}` prints just the rate

Answer (score 0):

you might want to man iperf to see what's supported.  Here's the latest from [2.0.10](https://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf2/)

```
   -f, --format
          [abkmgKMG]   format to report: adaptive, bits, Kbits, Mbits, KBytes, MBytes (see NOTES for more)
```